# VBA error: A value used in the formula is the wrong data type?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a function which generates a secret encoded message. It takes in three things: a string, for example, "testingtestingonetwothree", as well as the desired number of characters, for example 5, and the desired number of words, for example 5. It generates the message by starting at the first character, and extracting every fifth character through the string, putting these characters into a codeword, then starting at the second character and extracting every fifth character through the string, putting these into a second codeword, and so on. It just outputs a string, with the codewords separated by a space. So for this example it would produce: "tntnt egieh stntr tegwe isooe".

I'm okay at coding but new to VBA. I've made what I think is a valid function, but when it's used in the spreadsheet I get a #VALUE! error: "A value used in the formula is the wrong data type". This is the user defined function I made:

```
Function encode(strng, numchars, numwords)
Dim word As Integer
Dim step As Integer
Dim temp As String
Dim output As String

For word = 1 To numchars
step = word
temp = ""

Do While step <= Len(strng)
temp = temp & Mid(strng, 1, step)
step = step + numchars
Loop

If word = 1 Then output = temp Else output = output & " " & temp

Next word

encode = output

End Function
```

And when it's used in the spreadsheet I just call it, as in

```
=encode(A16,A7,A10)
```

Where A16 contains testingtestingonetwothree, A7 contains 5 and A10 contains 5.

Does my function seem okay? And is there anything you guys can see which could be giving the value error? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot for reading.

EDIT: This now outputs a value, but the wrong value. It outputs: "ttestintestingtesttestingtestingontestingtestingonetwot tetestingtestingtestitestingtestingonetestingtestingonetwoth ", when it should output: "tntnt egieh stntr tegwe isooe". Is there anything you guys can see that my function is doing wrong?

EDIT2: After fixing the Mid function, to
    temp = temp & Mid(strng, step, 1)
as per vacip's answer, the function now produces the correct answer.

Comment: It works here....I simply copied and pasted without any change....(It has to be in a separate module, not in the sheet module)

Comment: Just curious: when you say it works, you mean it gives you the desired output, or you just mean that it doesn't produce an error message?

Comment: Doesn't produce an error

Comment: The value error is now gone. However, after fixing the Mid function, it now produces "tienete ensgth sgtowr ttinoe", which isn't the "tntnt egieh stntr tegwe isooe" it should be outputting.

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce this new error. Try adding a breakpoint to your code, and go through it step-by-step, see if you can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @vacip Found the error, it was a silly spreadsheet mistake (I put 4 instead of 5). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, everyone says it works, but for me, it doesn't produce the desired output. What the...???

Anyway, I think your Mid function is in the wrong order, try it like this:

```
temp = temp & Mid(strng, step, 1)
```

Also, make sure to properly declare your variables, like this:

```
Function encode(strng As String, numchars As Integer, numwords As Integer) As String
```

I have also rewritten your IF statement, that one-line thing is strange for me...

```
If word = 1 Then
  output = temp
Else
  output = output & " " & temp
End If
```

This way it worked for me.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much! This is producing: "tienete ensgth sgtowr ttinoe" which is way more like it. However it should be outputting "tntnt egieh stntr tegwe isooe". I'll have a look through the function to see what it's doing, if you've got any ideas on what's going wrong I'd be very appreciative. Thanks again for this.

Comment: That is strange. For me, the output is: tntnt egieh stntr tegwe isooe. The only other part I have rewritten is your IF statement. I'll update my reply in a sec...

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I inputted the number of characters wrongly. Silly me. This is now working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have addressed the type problem. Here is a different suggestion. The cipher that you are describing is a simple transposition cipher, specifically a columnar transposition ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher#Columnar_transposition )

The way people did this pre-computer was to write the characters into a grid row by row then read them off column by column. In fact -- this is probably still the easiest way to implement it even with computers. Declare a variant which can be redimensioned to be an array with e.g. 5 columns (where 5 is the skip between letters) and the number of rows is chosen to be large enough so that the grid can hold the string. After you load up the characters row by row, read them off column by column using nested for loops.

Once you get a basic example working, you can try to implement a version which uses a key to determine the order that you read off the columns for added security.

Coding classical cryptography/cryptanalysis as an excellent way to learn a programming language. Almost the first thing I do when I try to learn a new language is to implement a Vigenere cipher in it. Even though it is long out of print and can be somewhat tricky to translate to modern dialects of Basic the book "Cryptanalysis for Microcomputers" by Caxton Foster is great fun and can be purchased for just a few dollars from online used bookstores.

Comment: Great answer, I hope this shows up on search results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your Function's type. So in this case I believe you would want

```
Function encode(strng, numchars, numwords) As String
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, this worked! Although it produces this: ttestintestingtesttestingtestingontestingtestingonetwot tetestingtestingtestitestingtestingonetestingtestingonetwoth. So it's not encoding properly or outputting it with spaces... my loops don't seem to be working. I'll edit the main question.

Comment: @vacip - way to make people look bad. I just answered the question, you fixed a bug the OP didn't know was there.

Comment: @justin Wow, sorry, I was not trying to make anyone look bad. For me, a problem is not considered "solved" until the desired outcome is reached. So I was really confused by everyone saying it works, while in reality, it didn't work. Different approach to a problem, that's all. Sorry if I was blunt or rude.

Comment: @vacip - You're not being blunt or rude, I was trying to be funny.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code exactly as it is, and it worked fine.

So, your problem may be:

- A certain argument of your function is not the right type. (I bet the `len` method is the problem in there).

Check if `A16` is really a string. If not, consider converting it to a string before if you want to pass numbers too:

```
Function encode(strng as variant, numchars as integer, numwords as integer) as string
    strng = str(strng)
```

Check also if `A7` and `A10` are really integers.

Comment: Thanks very much. The value error is fixed, but it's now outputting this: ttestintestingtesttestingtestingontestingtestingonetwot tetestingtestingtestitestingtestingonetestingtestingonetwoth", when it should be "tntnt egieh stntr tegwe isooe". By the way, what's the protocol on asking questions when a new error pops up? Should I ask a new question or just edit this current one?

Comment: I think it's up to you.... but now the problem is really a coding problem .... Normally, when an answer is considered a satisfatory answer to your question, you check it as answered.